# Xamarin webview not working in release mode -- Visual studio 2013 & 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, webview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a android webview application using xamarin for visual studio. When I run this application in debug mode it successfully works but when I try to change the configuration mode from debug to release then webview doesn't load the url.

Reason why I'm changing configuration mode bcz I'm unable to export android apk in debug mode. To export android apk I need to change configuration mode to release.

Comment: do you internet permissions enabled in your Manifest file?  I believe that in debug mode Android implicitly enables this for you, but in release mode you need to be sure it is explicitly enabled if you require it.

Comment: @Jason dude you are genius.......... thanks a lot n sorry for making silly mistake actually i'm very new to android stuff

Answer (score 5):

Adding below tag in androidmanifest.xml file will allow access to internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

All credit goes to Jason.